# Flask-Login: authentication via login_user() does not work and returns a 401 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

i'm trying to learn about flask right now and the tutorial I'm following right now (with some changes here and there) is about flask-login, the problem i'm running into right now is that even if I use the right login, it fails to authenticate and redirects me to a 401 error page. Here is my code

login manager

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

user class that I created

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def is_active(self):
        """True, as all users are active."""
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        """Return the email address to satisfy Flask-Login's requirements."""
        return self.email

    def is_authenticated(self):
        """Return True if the user is authenticated."""
        return self.authenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        """False, as anonymous users aren't supported."""
        return False
```

user_loader

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)
```

login

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, request.form.get('password')):
                user.authenticated = True
                db.session.commit()
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                return redirect(url_for('secrets'))
    return render_template("login.html")
```

and the route requiring auth

```
@app.route('/secrets')
@login_required
def secrets():
    print(current_user.name)
    return render_template("secrets.html", name=current_user.name)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by your implementation of the required user class prerequisites.

An example is that the method `get_id` is used to load the respective user within the `user_loader` callback. In this callback, however, you expect the primary key and no email address, evident from the database query.

To make implementing a user class easier, you can inherit from `UserMixin`, which provides default implementations for all of these properties and methods.

This is a simple example of using flask login. Please note that no server-side validation is carried out during registration. For example, it is not assumed that the received data really contain an email in the correct format.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    url_for
)
from flask_login import (
    LoginManager,
    UserMixin,
    current_user, 
    login_required,
    login_user,
    logout_user
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import (
    check_password_hash, 
    generate_password_hash
)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='your secret here', 
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///example.db', 
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS= False 
)
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('writeonly attr: password')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, value):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(value)

    def verify_password(self, value):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, value)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    keys = ('name', 'email', 'password')
    if request.method == 'POST' and all(k in request.form for k in keys):
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        name = request.form['name']
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user is None:
            user = User(name=name, email=email, password=password)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('.login'))
    return render_template('register.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=username).first()
        if user and user.verify_password(password):
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            return redirect(request.args.get('next', url_for('.secret')))
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('.login'))

@app.route('/secret')
@login_required
def secret():
    return f'{current_user.name} found the secret.'
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="username" id="username" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, the tutorial I'm following does use UserMixin (and provided that in template) but I ran into issues registering new users (I couldn't create a new entry in the DB with kwargs

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't create a new entry in the DB with kwargs"? The `UserMixin` doesn't change your database structure and doesn't change the constructor either.

Comment: For example, if I were to create a new entry like this

new_user = User(name=request.form.get('name'))

pycharm highlights it in yellow and yells at me that its an 'unexpected argument' which made me think that it wouldn't be valid though I didn't try to see if it still worked if I ignored it

Comment: I wrote you a little example and added it to the answer.